# How to convert all object properties (function) to async functions in flowtype?

Tags: flowtype

Given an object type that has functions as values I need to create object types with similar structure but having values as async functions.

Imagine this function

```
function convert(foo) {
  return async function(...args) {
    return foo(...args)
  }
}
```

Applied to values of this type

```
type Source = {
  foo: number => string,
  bar: string => number
}
```

So I get this type

```
type Result = {
  foo: number => Promise<string>,
  bar: string => Promise<number>
}
```

Is it possible in flow?